# Error on loading certificate with boost::asio

Tags: ssl, encryption, boost, openssl, boost-asio

I'm using *boost::asio* to establish encrypted connection between client and server applications. I generated a private key file and self signed certificate in the following way:

```
openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -key private_key.pem -out public_key.pem
```

The generated certificate is:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

In my program code, I have the following initialization of SSL context structure:

```
...
, m_sslContext(ssl::context::sslv23)
...
m_sslContext.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer | ssl::verify_fail_if_no_peer_cert);
m_sslContext.use_rsa_private_key_file("private_key.pem", ssl::context::pem);
m_sslContext.use_certificate_file("public_key.pem", ssl::context::pem);
...
```

**But** *use_ceritificate_file* method throws exception with message:

> use_certificate_file: no start line

Why does the function fail and what is the correct way to establish a secure connection with *boost::asio* wrapper around *OpenSSL*?

Comment: A public key isn't a certificate.

Comment: According to [this](http://superuser.com/questions/620121/what-is-the-difference-between-a-certificate-and-a-key-with-respect-to-ssl)  a certificate contains a public key, so I used it interchangeably.

Comment: A certificate contains a public-key, yes. But a public-key does not contain a certificate.

Comment: Oh well, your `public_key.pem` is neither a certificate nor a public-key. It's a certificate request. You have to process (sign) this certificate-request.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl

Comment: Yes I solved the problem when I generated the certificate in the way described in pointed by you post.  I will accept this answer if you post it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, a public-key isn't a certificate. Your public_key.pem however isn't a public-key either. It's a certificate-request which you'd normally send to a certificate-authority to sign it for you. Since you want to sign it yourself, you can check out [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl) to see how to sign your request.